# Windows Machine with Single login, Multiple Users need to push/pull to 1 GIT Clone, How?

Tags: python, windows, git, automation

I haven't been able to find anything related, so here we go.

I work in a manufacturing environment.  We have a piece of equipment that processes product and records data regarding each product.  That data is then post-processed and stored in two files.  This happens for each product produced.  The windows 7 machine that runs the process has one, single manufacturing login.  We have multiple users that will be using this one machine.  I need to have a single GIT clone that all users will be able to push/pull from, but our system requires that each user login to GIT.  Most of my post-processor is written in Python.  Our users/operators aren't necessary tech-savvy, so I am trying to automate this with Python.  I know little about GIT.  Please, help?

Comment: Do you mean -- you have a system with a single login, that all users use, but when they work with git, each should have separate credentials on this same system?

Comment: Yes, the computer only has a single login, but each user should push/pull from the same repo and with separate credentials.